# Weblogic custom Trust store switching to Java Standard Trust

Tags: ssl, weblogic, keystore, truststore

I am currently using Weblogic 12c(12.1.1.0). I have a peculiar problem and i am not able to solve it. 
I have configured the server to use Custom key-store and trust-store. 
I am using *-Djavax.net.debug=ssl* for debugging. 
When the server starts up the deployed application connects to another application for validations using https. During this connection its certificate is validated using the custom trust-store.

```
<2 Mar, 2016 8:37:51 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file D:\test\SSL\35patcha\trust.jks.>
```

The validation completes as expected and then the server starts up without reporting any errors. 
Now once i access the application on IE and perform a task which connects to a listener on the same application, the server loads Java's Standard Trust file, i.e cacerts.

```
trustStore is: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_5\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

I cannot find out why this is happening. This is not supposed to happen. Is there any particular reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening beacuse you have not defined the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore start parameter. I can also recommend you this link on how to configure SSL in Weblogic: https://jvzoggel.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/configuring-ssl-for-oracle-weblogic-and-ofmw/